# How to inject any bean that matches Qualifier in CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Using **CDI** in JakartaEE, I want to inject beans that match **any** of the given qualifiers, not the beans that match **all** the qualifiers:

```java
@MikeD class MikeDBean implements BBoy {}
@AdRock class AdRockBean implements BBoy {}
@MCA class MCABean implements BBoy {}

class Alive {

  @Inject
  @AdRock
  @MCA
  Instance<BBoy> performers;
}
```

In this given example, CDI will inject no bean, as there is no candidate qualified both `MCA` and `AdRock`. How can I inject both `MCA` and `AdRock`? In other words, how can I have CDI inject using **OR** rather than **AND** qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically do this by:

```
  @Inject
  @Any
  Instance<BBoy> performers;
```

Then performing a selection:

```
  Instance<BBoy> select = baseControllerInstance.select(new NamedLiteral...);
  ... select.get();
```

The value of AnnotationLiteral would be something like this:

```
 private class NamedLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<BBoy> implements AdRock, MCA {}
```

References:

- http://www.kurtsparber.de/?p=387
- https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup

Footguns:

- Instance<> and Provider<> are tricky masters. If you accidentally use them with dependent scoped beans, *you must* call the provider.destroy(instance) method or your application will leak!

Comment: That is indeed a solution. As a matter a fact I use this in a different part of the code, where fetching beans programatically is necessary. In the present use case, I am looking for a static configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, as Jonathan's solution is valid as well.

I ended up injecting dependencies on class declaration this way. The services are injected at init, and available as an iterable, allowing me to stream them.

```java
abstract class Song {

    Iterable<BBoy> mcs;

    protected void setMCs(BBoy... bboy) {
        this.mcs = Arrays.asList(bboy);
    }
}

class Alive extends Song {
    @Inject
    void init(@MCA BBoy mca, @AdRock BBoy adRock) {
        this.setMCs(mca, adRock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the method I outlined in my other answer, you'll need to write a CDI Portable Extension (this sounds scary, but is pretty easy actually). The thing about your ask is that you're actually wanting the *exact opposite* of what the CDI specification says to do. Which is, okay actually! That's what extensions are for.

What you would do is any annotation maybe `@Either({AdRock.class, MCA.class})`. Then your extension would implement this method:

```
<T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> pat) {
...
}
```

And listen for classes annotated with your `@Either` annotation. At that point, you can examine at the injected fields and determine what you want to do.

Refs:

- https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html
- https://www.next-presso.com/2017/02/nobody-expects-the-cdi-portable-extensions/

Examples (randomly googled):

- https://github.com/tomitribe/microscoped
- https://github.com/gunnarmorling/scripting-extension